# How to configure cgroup cpu quota for garden container running on ubuntu xenial

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cloud-foundry, garden-runc

I am trying to configure cpu quota for a garden container running on Ubuntu Xenial like below.

```
echo 1000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/garden/cpu.cfs_quota_us
```

Earlier while using Ubuntu Trusty, we were able to configure the cpu quota for a garden container by editing below file.

```
echo 1000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/garden/<container_guid>/cpu.cfs_quota_us
```

Could someone help me in configuring cpu quota for a garden container on Ubuntu Xenial OS.

Comment: Can you expand on the situation here? Provide some more context. When are you trying to do this? Where are you trying to do this? Is it on a Cell or in an app container? What are you trying to set a quota against, every container? a specific container? Do you intend that to survive a container restart? and include versions of everything you're running not just the stemcell, like bosh release versions and cf-deployment version.

Comment: Hi @DanielMikusa, we have noisy application running in multiple instances(containers) & consumes the lot of cpu in any particular diego cell. During this issue while we were using ubuntu trusty, we configure the cpu quota as 1000 for that particular application instance(container) so has to contain the cpu resources. However, we are not able to do it with Ubuntu Xenial VM. I assume is because of change in file system.
I hope this clarifies my issue over here.

Comment: Not totally sure why it would be necessary to apply manual limits. Can you expand? Cloud Foundry will apply limits to an app's CPU usage automatically. It's proportionate to your memory quota. It's shared based limits though, but that should generally be enough to make sure apps get their fair share of time on the CPU. You may just need to adjust memory limits so that you don't have one app with 64M and one big app with 4G. The big app is going to dominate the time because it will have a lot more shares. If you adjust the smaller app to have a larger memory limit, it will be more fair. HTH